# Go to URLs in batch with time interval PHP MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, batch-file

I am new to PHP and MySQL. I don't know if this is possible

Here is my MySQL table

```
    Id   url
    1    http://www.urla.com
    2    http://www.urlb.com
    3    http://www.urlc.com
    4    http://www.urld.com
    5    http://www.urle.com
    6    http://www.urlf.com
    7    http://www.urlg.com
    8    http://www.urlh.com
    9    http://www.urli.com
    10   http://www.urlj.com
```

Here is my php code

```
$getURL_List="select url from my_table";
$statement = $mysqli->prepare($getURL_List);

   //execute query
   $statement->execute();

   //store result
   $statement->store_result();

   //bind results variables
   $statement->bind_result($url);

   //count the result
   $countRows = $statement->num_rows;

   while ($statement->fetch()) {

   Questions: 
  ============ 
 How do I get the first 5 url returned from my query and open them in the browser

1    http://www.urla.com - go to this URL (open it in the browser)
2    http://www.urlb.com - go to this URL (open it in the browser)
3    http://www.urlc.com - go to this URL (open it in the browser)
4    http://www.urld.com - go to this URL (open it in the browser)
5    http://www.urle.com - go to this URL (open it in the browser)
```

So, 5 browser windows will be opened

then, wait for 5 seconds then get the next 3 urls

```
6    http://www.urlf.com - go to this URL (open it in the browser)
7    http://www.urlg.com - go to this URL (open it in the browser)
8    http://www.urlh.com - go to this URL (open it in the browser)
```

So, 3 browser windows will be opened

and repeating the above step of getting 3 urls until no more url is left to go through.Then the operation is ended.

```
   }
$statement->close();
?>
```

Please help guide me to the right direction so that I could solve this problem. Any input or guidance you could provide will be greatly appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: php can't open your browser for you. you'd need something in the browser already (e.g. some JS code) to open the urls for you.

Comment: Web driver?  i think this one has some pretty big names on it, FB/Selenium.  https://github.com/facebook/php-webdriver.  However your question asking how do you get the first 5 results worries me, i think if you dont know that, this topic should be about that first, because that's another topic.  For the timing, you can use sleep, sleep 5 seconds in a for each loop, take 5 at a time, open with a web driver..  If this helps i can create an answer with webdriver info on it for you, unless theres another topic here already for that.

Comment: It's not true that php cannot open your browser for you. As long as you run php on your computer (where your browser is installed), php can open it using exec() function. For a more complete solution, you can use the Symfony Process component.

Comment: @BrianThomas Thank you for your suggestion. I have been looking at the webdriver.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Answer**
You can use a Web driver.

I think this one has some pretty big names on it, https://github.com/facebook/php-webdriver

For the timing, you can use sleep http://php.net/manual/en/function.sleep.php
Sleep it 5 seconds on each iteration in a for each loop, take 5 at a time, open with a web driver..

If you have any more specifics i can put a couple examples.